# Hidden form field value not really changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, why do I get the new value in the final alert(), but the old value on form submit (and when viewing hidden field with firebug)?

Hidden field element inside form tags:

```
<input type="hidden" id="shipping_1" name="shipping_1" value="3.99">
```

When ShipTo dropdown is selected, jQuery is used to update the field value:

```
$('#ShipSelect').change(function(e) {
    var ss = $('#ShipSelect').val();
    if (ss=='International') {
        alert("International orders add $10 S&H");
        ship1 = ($('#shipping_1').val())*1 + 10;
        alert('Shipping_1 val is now: ' + ship1);
        $('#shipping_1').val(ship1);
        alert('Reading the field directly: ' + $('#shipping_1').val());
    }
});
```

The alerts show that $10 has been added to the hidden field value. So far so good.

However, when the DOM is viewed with Firebug (or in Chrome DevTools mode) *AND/OR* when the BuyNow button is pushed, the `shipping_1` field is at the old value ($10 short).

---

UPDATE:
I saw [this promising post](http://drupal.org/node/1342858), which exactly describes my problem, but the solution did not work. This is what they suggested:

```
document.form_name.field_name.value = your_value
```

Therefore, I commented out this line:

```
$('#shipping_1').val(ship1);
```

and replaced it with:

```
document.paypal_cart.shipping_1.value = ship1;
```

The result is no different from what I have now. The old value is still submitted (and visible when viewed with firebug).  DO I need to use .on() somehow to "fix" the changed value to the form or something?

Comment: Why are you relying on the client to calculate the shipping costs? What if I used my JavaScript debugger to set the value of this hidden field to 0? Would you not charge me shipping?

Comment: You wont be able to see changes done dynamically with javascript by viewing the source, but if you use the console you should see the value change.

Comment: Test `$('#shipping_1').attr('value', ship1);` to be sure. I see no fault

Comment: `($('#shipping_1').val())*1` -> consider `parseFloat($('#shipping_1').val())`.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for that. Back to the drawing board. Still not understanding why the value is wrong when it arrives at PPal though.

Comment: The code sample is missing the closing `);`, is that a typo?

Comment: @adeneo Thot so, that's why I mentioned Chrome's dev mode (Ctrl+Sh+i). Tried in Firebug also, same result. Old value.

Comment: @clav Good eyes. Yes, code is a snippet. So, typo. Thanks for catching it. (Updated)

Comment: Can we see the rest of your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PeT66/1/

it is simplified a little I think you missed the closing bracket

```
$('#ShipSelect').change(function(e) {
    var ss = $('#ShipSelect').val();
    alert("International orders add $10 S&H");
    ship1 = ($('#shipping_1').val())*1 + 10;
    alert('Shipping_1 val is now: ' + ship1);
    $('#shipping_1').val(ship1);
    alert('Reading the field directly: ' + $('#shipping_1').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My post was a snippet and I failed to provide the closing `);`, but it is present in my actual code (just a lot further down). I updated the question to fix that. As to your answer, what I have now works exactly the same as what you provided.

Comment: you don't see the new value for the hidden field still? I checked in Firebug and it does change